# ncurses bug, when resizing both height and width of terminal

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

I am learning ncurses. I made simple program to handle SIGWINCH signal.

Main thread displays UI and then waits for user to quit program by pressing 'q' key.

When terminal is resized, programs handles SIGWINCH signal and displays UI again.

When I change width of terminal and press 'q', program exits. When I change height of terminal and press 'q', program exits. BUT when I change height of terminal and then width of terminal, and then I press 'q', the program doesn't exit! I needed to press 'q' second time to exit program.

So, why pressing 'q' single time not exiting my program when I change both height and width?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <signal.h>

WINDOW *win1;

void paint_window(void){
    int x, y;

    refresh();

    clear();
    refresh();

    getmaxyx(stdscr, y, x);

    bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    refresh();

    win1 = newwin(3, x - 4, 1, 2);
    box(win1, 0, 0);
    wbkgd(win1, COLOR_PAIR(2));

    wattron(win1, COLOR_PAIR(3));
    mvwprintw(win1, 1, 1, "MAX X: %d, MAX Y: %d. Press 'q' to exit.", x, y);
    wattroff(win1, COLOR_PAIR(3));

    wrefresh(win1);
}

void sig_handler(int sig_num){
    delwin(win1);
    endwin();
    paint_window();
}

int main(void) {
    int ch;

    initscr();

    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);

    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED);

    paint_window();

    signal(SIGWINCH, sig_handler);

    while(1){
        ch = getch();

        if(ch == 'q' || ch == 'Q'){
            delwin(win1);
            endwin();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When size changed one time - then `q` works correct, but when more than one time (it's doesn't matter height or width) - then `q` doesn't work correct.

Comment: yes correct. Yes it doesn't matter height or width if I change any of those more than one time.

Comment: A couple observations... 1) The reason for having to hit 'q' twice is that there seems to be another value in the stdscr input stream.  From my experimenting, the first value in the stream is __410__ is __octal 0632__ which is __KEY_RESIZE__ in ncurses.   2) The problem __goes away__ when the line __keypad(stdscr, TRUE);__ is commented out.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer thanks, great observations. I don't need KEYPAD, I am disabling, now my program working fine.